# Is it possible to swap between Ubuntu And Win8.1 if i install Ubuntu on a external HDD

Tags: system-installation

I am currently running Windows 8.1 and I was wondering if I am able to install Ubuntu to my external HDD (It already has stuff on it but it still has a lot of space) and swap between the 2 operating systems. If possible when I update Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 will the updates go to the HDD that the OS was installed 2. Also if I can boot ubuntu from a external HDD how do I swap between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "swap" you mean booting into the different operating system (OS), then yes, it is entirely possible. Just install Ubuntu on the external hard drive, then ask the bios to boot into the external hard drive by default. Upon installation, Ubuntu will install the Grub (bootloader) that will allow you to choose which operating system to start. If you unplug the external hard drive, it will boot straight into Windows.

To recap:

1. Install Ubuntu on your external hard drive. It will automatically detect the other drive with Windows on it and set the bootloader accordingly.
2. Go in your bios and set the boot priority to External hard drive -> Internal HDD

---

However, if by swap, you mean actively flipping from one OS to the the other, well, you can't do that. It's not just two different programs running at the same time that you can flip between. The operating system (OS) is responsible for the interactions between the hardware pieces of the computer. The OS needs to have full control of the hardware at all times.

If you REALLY want to flip between the two systems, you can use a virtual machine. Basically, you can set, say, Ubuntu, to be able to start Windows inside itself. You would obtain the layers:

Hardware-> Ubuntu -> "faked hardware" -> Windows

Comment: Edited answer, because I realised I answered badly.

Comment: Before i go. I already have stuff on the Ext HDD i want to use for Ubuntu. I've heard that when i install ubuntu to the HDD it will Erase the files i have on it and it will only have ubuntu. Is this true?

Comment: You will have to partition the drive if you do not want to lose previous files. It would actually be a good idea to do that, since Windows has a hard accessing files in a Linux partition.

The Ubuntu installer can take care of the partitioning.

But as with anything, make backups before messing with your drives!

Comment: Keep in mind that programs are operating-system specific. They are stored on the partition the OS is installed. Everything you have installed on windows is actually stored on the hard drive Windows is installed. If you boot into Ubuntu, you will have access to the programs installed on the Ubuntu hard drive. Yes, you have access to your Windows partition, but the programs in windows **will not run** on Linux: you will need to install linux-specific versions of the programs, if they exist.